# xargs and ex command input

Tags: redirect, xargs

Can someone explain why when attempting to run an ex command script on a number of files, this works:

```
for x in `ls *`;do ex $x <excmds;done;
```

but this doesn't:

```
ls *|xargs -i ex {} <excmds
```

The first will execute ex and run commands in "excmds" for each file
The second, I'm not sure what it does, but it doesn't change any files.
I'm guessing the re-direct is a problem, and doesn't act on each execution of xargs?
Is there some way to do it with xargs?
(yet another question I've raised on xargs - maybe I should stop using it :( )

Comment: In this case `xargs` will read its input from `excmds` **instead** of the output of `ls`.

Comment: hmm, OK, that's a bit obvious now I look at it. Looks like this should be the answer, rather than a comment, though I would still like to know how to do it with xargs

Comment: Joe I didn't answer because I had no real answer (only this comment). It also seems like `xargs` is the wrong tool for this job, as you want to execute some command *exactly once* for each file. `xargs` is useful for executing commands that can handle multiple inputs at once.

Comment: to see what `xargs` does, run it with `-t` option. Also I suspect `ls *` is the right tool (try it in a folder with subfolders!)

Comment: @Jakob Thanks, didn't know about -t, and I also reread the answer about GNU Parallel, and noticed a "\" in front of <. Maybe the answer? But no, despite it looking correct:  
`ls y*|xargs -i -t ex {} \<excmds`  
`ex ya <excmds`  
it then just hangs!
Assume you meant ls is *not* the right tool

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
ls * | parallel ex {} \<excmds
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

10 seconds installation:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```